# Are two .awaits (in the same async block or function) executed in parallel?

Tags: rust, async-await

I was trying to learn async/await and came up with the simple code below:

```
const N: usize = 100000;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");


    let mut my_array = [0u32; N];
    let mut my_vector = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..my_array.len() {
        my_array[i] = i as u32;
    }

    for i in 0..N {
        my_vector.push((i * i) as u32);
    }

    let mut array_sum = 0;
    let mut vector_sum = 0;

    async_std::task::block_on(
        async {
            array_sum = sum_slice(&my_array).await;
            vector_sum = sum_slice(&my_vector).await;

            println!("Sum of array = {}", array_sum);
            println!("Sum of vector = {}", vector_sum);
        }
    );

println!("Total sum = {}", array_sum + vector_sum);

}

async fn sum_slice(slice: &[u32]) -> u64 {
    println!("Summing...{} to {}", slice.first().unwrap(), slice.last().unwrap());
    slice.iter().fold(0, |a, &b| a + b as u64) 
}
```

In this code, are the two calls to the `sum_slice()` function really running asynchronously in two different threads and in parallel?

I'm asking this because the line:

```
println!("Summing...{} to {}", slice.first().unwrap(), slice.last().unwrap());
```

always prints the array first, like:

```
Summing...0 to 99999
Summing...0 to 1409865409
```

EDIT:
Modified the code this way... which of the way between (1) and (2) is preferred?

```
use futures::join;

const N: usize = 10000;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {

    let mut my_array = [0u32; N];
    let mut my_vector = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..my_array.len() {
        my_array[i] = i as u32;
    }

    for i in 0..N {
        my_vector.push((i * i) as u32);
    }

    //(1) st way
    let array_sum = sum_slice(&my_array).await;
    let vector_sum = sum_slice(&my_vector).await;

    println!("Sum of array = {}", array_sum);
    println!("Sum of vector = {}", vector_sum);
    println!("Total sum = {}", array_sum + vector_sum);

    //(2) nd way
    async_std::task::block_on(
        async {
            let (array_sum, vector_sum) = join!(sum_slice(&my_array), sum_slice(&my_vector));

            println!("Sum of array = {}", array_sum);
            println!("Sum of vector = {}", vector_sum);
            println!("Total sum = {}", array_sum + vector_sum);
        });
}

async fn sum_slice(slice: &[u32]) -> u64 {
    println!("Summing...{} to {}", slice.first().unwrap(), slice.last().unwrap());
    slice.iter().fold(0, |a, &b| a + b as u64)   
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT 2:

If I try to run this code in the context of the above, I get a panic:

```
use futures::join;
use std::sync::Arc;    

const N: usize = 10000;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {

    let mut my_array = [0u32; N];
    let mut my_vector = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..my_array.len() {
        my_array[i] = i as u32;
    }

    for i in 0..N {
        my_vector.push((i * i) as u32);
    }  

    let a_arc = Arc::new(my_array);
    let v_arc = Arc::new(my_vector);

    let arr = a_arc.clone();
    let vec = v_arc.clone();

    println!("Try 0:");
    async_std::task::spawn(
          async move {            
             let future1 = sum_slice(&*arr);
             let future2 = sum_slice(&*vec);

              let (array_sum, vector_sum) = join!(future1, future2);

              println!("Sum of array = {}", array_sum);
              println!("Sum of vector = {}", vector_sum);
              println!("Total sum = {}", array_sum + vector_sum);
       });
}

async fn sum_slice(slice: &[u32]) -> u64 {
    println!("Summing...{} to {}", slice.first().unwrap(), slice.last().unwrap());
    slice.iter().fold(0, |a, &b| a + b as u64)  
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Try 0:
thread 'async-std/executor' panicked at 'cannot access stdout during shutdown', src\libstd\io\stdio.rs:487:25
stack backtrace:
```

Could someone point out the error I'm making please?
My objective is to run the two sum_slices() tasks as async of each other and main.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I think i finally figured it out.

```
    const N: usize = 10000;        

   fn main() {
        let mut my_array = [0u32; N];
        let mut my_vector = Vec::new();

        for i in 0..my_array.len() {
            my_array[i] = i as u32;
        }

        for i in 0..N {
            my_vector.push((i * i) as u32);
        }

        let task2 = task::spawn(async move {
            let res = sum_slice(&my_array).await;
            println!("done....task 2");
            res
        });

        let task3 = task::spawn(async move {
            let res = sum_slice(&my_vector).await;
            println!("done....task 3");
            res
        });

        task::block_on(async {
            println!("waiting for the tasks...");

            let res2 = task2.await;
            let res3 = task3.await;

            println!("task2 and task3 ended with result {}", res2+res3);
        }
}
```

Now it's computing things async to each other:

```
waiting for the tasks...
Summing...0 to 9999
Summing...0 to 99980001
done....task 2
done....task 3

task2 and task3 ended with result 333333330000
```

Comment: It's running asynchronously, yes, but that doesn't imply it running on different threads (it does not, [`async_std::task::block_on`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.5.0/async_std/task/fn.block_on.html) runs it all on the current thread) or in parallel (it does not, as your code is written to do it in series; look into [`futures::join!`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/macro.join.html), for instance). Just because it's asynchronous doesn't mean that it's parallel programming, because that's not the really problem it attempts to solve.

Comment: @Frxstrem Thanks! I got it. I need to spawn the tasks from the main thread, most probably.

Comment: When I modified the code like this: let array_sum = sum_slice(&my_array);
    let vector_sum = sum_slice(&my_vector);
    let (array_sum, vector_sum) = join!(array_sum, vector_sum); let sum_array = array_sum.await;
    let sum_vector = vector_sum.await; It throws error let sum_array = array_sum.await;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `u64`

Comment: Looks like I figured it out how to call the join!() correctly. Thanks.